# How to check if the line of code displays error

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do something with lists. I would like to learn this.

So let's say I have this

```
_list = [1,2,3]
```

I want to check values of elements inside the list while iterating,

```
 for x in range(len(_list)):
    if _list[x] == _list[x+1]:
        print(_list[x])
```

But the problem here is it throws an error while checking _list[-1] how do i solve this?

I tried -

```
if _list[x] != _list[-1]
assert _list[3]
```

These doesnt seem convenient,
I am thinking of trying try and except block but is any other option is available?

Comment: You're comparing every element of the list to the next element and printing it if they are the same. What do you expect to happen for the last element in the list? So, you probably want to stop just before the end of the list? So `for x in range(len(_list)-1)`?

Comment: Omit the last element `for x in range(len(_list) - 1):`, logically it does not belong in there as it has no successor to compare against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your loop go till `len(_list) -1`:

```
for x in range(len(_list) - 1):
    if _list[x] == _list[x+1]:
        print(_list[x])
```